# Can "heavy duty" mean violently (in german: heftig)?

Tags: german

In Starcraft2, a RTS game, one of the characters says "heavy duty", and in german it's translated to simply "heftig" (which, to me can be simply translated to "heavy")

Now, i think the Blizzard team knows its job, but:

is (heavy duty)=(heftig(german))

This is mainly asked to people which know both languages. But feel free to answer.

English quotes after the character aqquired a literally heavy duty Machine(Odin) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW9Hcm7Adz0

German quotes: sorry, but i didnt found one containing all odin-quotes (the character is also used as a normal unit)

Comment: (a) more context is needed to understand what the character really means when it says "heavy duty"; (b) your question appears to be asking about whether they chose the correct German word, which is clearly not on-topic here at ENGLISH Language and Usage.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion oh, i can delete the question as the com whishes, and make it in german SE, sorry but i diddnt thought that way. As to context: i try to get the direct context, by replaying ;)

Comment: *Heavy duty* has a number of different metaphoric meanings.  Without context it's impossible to say which is intended.

Comment: If *Heavy Duty* is used as an exclamation, "Whoa, heavy duty, man!" It means whatever was just done was done with quite a lot of overkill. And, "Whoa. Heavy, man!" could be said in the same context with approximately the same meaning: "That's some serious shit man!" And in the context of a game that could very well mean, "I can tell by the amount of violence you used to do that you were trying to prove a point."

Comment: @Jim so in esscence it can mean "with cannons on sparrows" when used as an exclamation? that makes much sense.

Comment: Can you find a YT video of a SC2 game that displays the use of 'heavy duty'? On the other hand, I agree with @Hellion's second point above: *your question appears to be asking about whether they chose the correct German word, which is clearly not on-topic here at ENGLISH Language and Usage.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack done

Comment: @saturatedexpo *Heavy-duty* does not mean *heavy*, but a heavy machine gun is probably also going to be a *heavy-duty* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Heavy duty](https://youtu.be/NFhgVeoFOhA?t=73)* is one of those phrases in English whose official meaning is quite specific ("Designed to withstand hard usage without breaking") but in slang can mean almost anything.  As slang, it conveys a vague sense of strength, sturdiness, or resilience in the one hand, or intensity and vigor, requiring strength and resilience to withstand, on the other.

A physical object, like a tool or a machine, that is heavy-duty is likely to be heavy in consequence, but it seems more likely in a video game that something else was meant.

Comment: although this is quite answering, i wait a little to accept is as an asnwer ;) because i didnt got the exact context. don't worry ;)